# How can I specify Dockerfile build in buildConfig for OpenShift Online?

Tags: openshift, openshift-3

Openshfit details:
Paid Professional version.
Version Information:
[image]

Been trying to create a build from a Dockerfile in Openshift.
Its tough going.
So I tried to use the existing templates in the Cluster Console.
One of which is the Docker one. When i press "Try it" it generates a sample BuildConfig, when I try to then Create it, it gives me the error:
[image]
(i have now raised the above in the Origin upstream issue tracker)
Anyhoo...anyone know how to specify a **buildConfig** an image from a Dockerfile in a git repo? I would be grateful to know.

Comment: Which template did you use that had the Dockerfile build option with "Try It"?

Answer (score 0):

You can see the build strategies allowed for OpenShift Online on the product website: https://www.openshift.com/products/online. Dockerfile build isn't deprecated, it's just explicitly disallowed in OpenShift Online. You can build your Dockerfile locally and push it directly to the OpenShift internal registry (commands for `docker login` and `docker push` are on your cluster's About page).

However, in other environments (not OpenShift Online), you can specify a Dockerfile build as follows and providing a Git Repo with a Dockerfile contained within (located at `BuildConfig.spec.source.contextDir`)

```
strategy:
  type: Docker
```

There are additional options that can be configured for a Dockerfile build as well, outlined in https://docs.okd.io/latest/dev_guide/builds/build_strategies.html#docker-strategy-options.

Comment: This is of no practical use Will. Sorry to say this. I know my options in OC without this strategy. By not allowing it, as part of a buildConfig negates a whole swathe of deployment category which are core to the requirements of an container driven platform. Thanks all the same...and just in case you want a concrete example...here is one: most Docker hub images will not out of the box run on OC. ApacheMQ for instance. So I have had to create a Dockerfile that is compliant. Now, I want to use this to specify a buildConfig which only can happen at the cluster level and is not available.

Comment: With a compliant Dockerfile, you can `docker build` it locally, and `docker push` it directly to the cluster.

Comment: Thank you. I raised the issue with Openshift Origin and they have a ticket on their backlog tracking it...albeit not at the Cluster level and instead at the project level: https://trello.com/c/6CuBSnFF/733-5-add-easy-docker-automated-build-to-add-to-project-options-build-onboarding

Comment: Also to respond to your answer about pushing the image directly...the whole idea of a buildConfig, ImageStreams and hooks into a repo, is that I can then specify my build policies for the image(s) and the cluster as a whole, so I do not have to manually do anything...or have to script stuff. Again, _this_ is the critical point for me. I can do it manually, but that is not the point.

Comment: Finally, and i found this in the above ticket on trello, you will see (and I will try it later) that it is possible to do it with the the CLI oc command...but again, I have not tried this yet: https://github.com/openshift/origin-web-console/issues/1399